# Display Block По времени

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Привет всем.

как можно сделать в Js Display Block по часам?

```
<div class="08" style="display:block"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="09" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="10" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="11" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="12" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="13" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="14" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
<div class="15" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="16" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="17" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div> 
<div class="default"  style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
```

Например с 9:00 до 09:59 утра он должен классу 9 дать Display:block а диву с классом 8 дать Display:none.

А если например 18:00 до 07:59 дать display:block классу default и дисплэй ноне классу 17.

как такое можно реализовать? кто может помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блок будет зеленым c каждой 20 секунды по каждую 40вую.

```js
const block = test;
calculate_timeout = seconds => {
  now = new Date(), next = new Date();
  next.setSeconds(seconds);
  if(next.getTime() <= now.getTime())
    next.setMinutes(next.getMinutes()+1);
  return next.getTime() - now.getTime();
}
(function timer_callback() {
  let now = new Date;
  if(now.getSeconds() >= 20 && now.getSeconds() < 40){
    block.classList.add('now');
    setTimeout(timer_callback, calculate_timeout(40));
  }else{
    block.classList.remove('now');
    setTimeout(timer_callback, calculate_timeout(20));
  }
})();
```

```css
#test.now{
  background: green;
}
#test{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: как можно сделать в Js Display Block по часам? Вот так.

Comment: Я специально выбрал секунды, чтобы было наглядно видно что оно работает.

Comment: ваш ответ не отвечает на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Ну так ответьте сами на конкретный вопрос, в чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо. 

вот как идея что будет дальше...  

https://jsfiddle.net/pkgzwct6/39/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pkgzwct6/48/ покажет который сейчас час, с 9 до 18) в остальное время ничего не покажет

Answer (score 0):

Это только для одного времени и одного элемента. Для остальных повторить не сложно. Для проверки, можно установить в строку `if (hours >= 9 && hours < 10) {` свой интервал времени, по своему часовому поясу.

```js
setInterval(function repeatTimer() {
    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours >= 9 && hours < 10) {
        document.body.querySelector('div[class="09"]').style.display = 'block';
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="08" style="display:block"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="09" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="10" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="11" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="12" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="13" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="14" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="15" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="16" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="17" style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
 <div class="default"  style="display:none"><h3> lorem 60</h3> </div>
```

Comment: Итого 86 398 лишних телодвижений в сутки)

Comment: @Darth я не спорю, можно оптимизировать, для этого нужно чуть больше времени, его пока нет, поэтому пока что так. Ну как вариант каждые 2 секунды проверять, уже в два раза меньше движений)

Comment: Возьмите мой ответ, замените Seconds на Hours, Minutes на Days, 20 на 9, 40 на 10, test на `document.body.querySelector('div[class="09"]')` и вуаля

Comment: @Darth че-то пока что в падлу, для чего?)

Comment: Чтоб время не тратить на оптимизацию

Comment: на досуге попробую